# How to get Stored SQLite data from internal storage

Tags: android, export, android-sqlite

I stored some data into SQLite database, and now i have to get those data from device's internal storage any how, i am using below code but nothing happening when doing tap on button

```
File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();
FileChannel source=null;
FileChannel destination=null;
  String currentDBPath = "/data/data/app.church.sophie/databases/churchdb.db";
           String backupDBPath = "SAMPLE_DB_NAME";
File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);
File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);
        try {
        source = new FileInputStream(currentDB).getChannel();
        destination = new FileOutputStream(backupDB).getChannel();
        destination.transferFrom(source, 0, source.size());
        source.close();
        destination.close();
        Toast.makeText(ExportDataActivity.this, "DB Exported!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
         }
}
```

Comment: The correct path is `/data/data/app.church.sophie/databases/church.db` and not `/data/app.church.sophie/databases/churchdb` (note there's 2 **/data**). Also note that the db name should end in .db (so, `church.db` instead of `churchdb`).

Comment: @BobMalooga I done the changes but issue still not resolved

Comment: You're missing a slash here: `"/data/data"+ "app.church.sophie"` it should be `"/data/data/app.church.sophie"`. Then, may I ask you why ALL THESE CONCATENATIONS on a single string? it's **counter-performant**...

Comment: @BobMalooga still not resolved can you show me the any other way or code to get data ?

Comment: Now, you code is a bit confused. Change this `File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);` to `File currentDB = new File(currentDBPath);` and this `File backupDB = new File(sd, backupDBPath);` to `File backupDB = new File(sd + "/" + backupDBPath);`